# bootstrap modal opens new bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which is filled with a form from another file, as below:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Invoice</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
// Fill modal with content from link href
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
```

HTML link somewhere in the page:

```
<a data-remote='false' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' href='submit1.php' class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block'>Invoice</a>
```

submit.php is a form:

```
<form action="" id="form1" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The above code works fine. After the submit1.php is loaded into the modal, I want to have the submit button of that form do the following:

1. Submit the form data
2. Load the response in the same or new modal window (the response will be a new form)

How can I do this? Either using a new href or using ajax.

Comment: you can do it both ways, `Ajax` or `href` but preferable is `Ajax`

Comment: Here an example:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form

Comment: Or this one: http://insightandinsanity.com/build-a-simple-php-jquery-and-ajax-powered-contact-form/